# Jquery: save field values into a multidimensional array

Tags: jquery, arrays, checkbox

### Js Fiddle

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CwPCs/121/)

### What I Require

In the above fiddle I have got 2 text fields, a checkbox and a text. What I require is I need to get the checkbox value and 2 text field values into an array of this structure.

```
 array= array(
              [0]=>array(
                         [0]=>checkbox1,
                         [1]=>field1,
                         [2]=>input1),
              [1]=>array(
                         [0]=>checkbox2,
                         [1]=>field2,
                         [2]=>input2)

              )
```

### Edit

Im building this application in codeigniter. I need to post this array using ajax and process it in php. So I want the values in either array format or json as shown above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
$('#add').click(function() {
    var result = $('#mytable tr:has(input:checkbox:checked)').map(function() {
        var $this=$(this), row =[];
        row.push($this.find('input[name="checker1"]').is(':checked'));
        row.push($this.find('input[name="field1"]').val());
        row.push($this.find('input[name="input1"]').val());
        return [row]
    }).get();
    console.log(result);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/TjuVW/)

Comment: Yeah thats what I wass looking for.

Comment: can you edit the code such that only row with checked checkbox of a class are obtained.